# How can I validate a stellar address in Python?

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk

I am using [python-sdk](https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base) to perform stellar operations. Now I need to validate a stellar address. I know that the JS sdk has got a function `StrKey.isValidEd25519PublicKey(address);` however I cannot find the same in Python SDK.

Any idea, how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out: https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base/blob/6329db3658c9b646a69c567019d95b41b7363eee/stellar_base/utils.py#L251

```
def is_valid_address(address):
try:
    return decode_check('account', address)
except (DecodeError, TypeError):
    raise StellarAddressInvalidError('Invalid Stellar Address: {}'.format(address))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats how i have done it:

```
from stellar_sdk.exceptions import Ed25519PublicKeyInvalidError

def check_stellar_address(address):
    try:
        Account(account_id=address, sequence=0)
        return True

    except Ed25519PublicKeyInvalidError:
        return False
```